# Firefox 4 Beta 12 -- Move Link URLs back to Address Bar?

Tags: firefox, address-bar

The latest beta of Firefox seems to have moved the link URL display from the address bar to a small box in the bottom left. I was happy with them in the address bar, so is there a way to move them back?

Comment: This is a new feature that many people requested. Also, I think you mean beta 12?

Comment: @Randolph: I certainly didn't request it ;) and yes, i mean beta 12.

Comment: Reading the forums, I think you're in the minority. A lot of people are happy it has moved, and no clear evidence of a way to move it back.

Comment: I loved that they moved it to the location bar, it makes so much sense. Like: "you are here > here's where you're going"

Of course, it was odd at first, and it took me a few weeks to get used to it, but now that it's second nature to be, they go and change it to Chrome's ham-fisted "overlay" solution. Ugh! There's all this white space in the location bar begging to be used, yet they decide to overlay it on top of page content?!?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the [Link Location Bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/link-location-bar/) Addon to add it back.
[image]